# Looping through lists while passing values to a function

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist

Edit:

I have lists which contains multiple values and I'm trying to loop through the values and passing them as parameters to a function. However, only one value is being passed to the method.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for (x = 0; x < time.length; x++) 
    {
      checkTime(time[x], x);
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here's the function where I'm passing the values:

```
 public void checkTime(String time, int channel){
     //displayNotif is a function that displays notifications to the user
     //the format is displayNotif(channel, message, title)
     displayNotif(channel, "The time is: " + time, "Time Notification"); }
```

Since it may be happening so fast, I've tried passing another dynamic value to ensure the notifications are displayed through different channels but I'm still getting only one out/notification.

```
public void displayNotif(Integer c, String msg, String title){
            notificationChannel();
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, TIME_CHANNEL);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_sms_notif);
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            builder.setLargeIcon(bit);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(msg);
            builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(msg));
            builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            notificationManagerCompat.notify(s, builder.build());
        }
```

I've tried the following as well and it displays all values:

```
for (x = 0; x < time.length; x++) 
    {
      displayNotif(x, "Time is: " + time[x], "Time");
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual and expected behavior?

Comment: Try to log the time.length value to see if it is causing the problem

Comment: what is the actual size of time array. may be size of the the array is one

Comment: is that value always the last value?

Comment: Expected behavior is all values should be passed to the function through the loop so the function can return/display the output. I displayed the time.length value through a toast and the value is correct.

Comment: Yes @codeMagic I currently have 2 values and it seems only the last one is displayed/passed correctly.

Comment: Can't say exactly as we can't see the other function. But it's passing both values you just don't see the output change because it happens so quickly. Log the output and you'll see what's happening. You can also set breakpoints, toasts, or whatever and do some basic debugging first.

Comment: @Vincent you need to share the contents of x before the loop, the definition of function `checkTime` and the expected output of the program if you expect any kind of relevant help.

Comment: Please check my edited question @rhobincu. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent you now have three arguments for the call and only two for the function declaration. Also, we now need `displayNotif` to see what it does with the provided strings.

Comment: Also, you should log the contents for array `time`

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: Do you try with `setAutoCancel(false)` because I think when you send next notification the previous is cancel because of this.

Comment: What is the value of s in notificationManagerCompat.notify(s, builder.build());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to solve this but my solution seems to okay for me at the moment. By the way, thank you to everyone who responded to my question.

Here's what I did:

1. I passed the list to the function inside of looping through the values and passing them to the function one by one.
     //time is the list
   checkTime(time);
2. I did the loop inside function and got the result that I need.

Here's my code:

```
public void checkTime(String[] time)
{
   for(int x = 0; x < time.length; x++){
   displayNotif(x, "The time is: " + time[x], "Time Notification");      
   }         
}
```